# application redundancy with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, redundancy

we are trying to write a service for windows and need to come up with a plan for redundancy, so that if something in the application fails, it is brought back up again. i'm wondering if i can use multi-threading to accomplish this.

my idea is to create two threads which each handle separate tasks. i would like to also have each thread monitor the other thread to make sure its still running, if its not, then it should start up a new instance of that thread.
does this sound feasible? what threading techniques would i use: mutexes, shared memory, semaphores, etc...?
if this is not the correct approach, then what might be, just write two separate services and use IPC?

Comment: It really depends what you mean by "something in the application fails". Can you give some examples of failures from which you'd like to recover?

Comment: The hard part will be figuring out where the other thread left of and picking up from there, and also making sure that you don't keep hitting the same error and restarting over and over (forever).  That will consume a LOT of system resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the easiest way to get your service to restart on failure is to let Windows do it.  You just configure the service to auto restart, its really easy.  You can also do this programatically durring the service installer.  For a guide on how to do this, see this post: [Building a Windows Service – Part 4: Extending the Service Installer](http://csharptest.net/955/building-a-windows-service-part-4-extending-the-service-installer/).

As for this providing "redundancy", this does not.  The proper definition of redundancy would mean that you have more than one of them.  This could be using multiple services, or using multiple services on multiple hosts more likely.  Having multiple services on a single host is easier since you can use a mutex to synchronize if needed.

> The real question is what is this service doing?

If your service is polling for tasks, say from a database or message queue, then the synchronization is taken care of for you.  Just model your database such that multiple services can all run and process work independently without duplicating work.  Now you have redundancy.

Comment: just letting windows handle it would be best i guess. i'm not really looking for a way to make the service "pick up where it left off". i was just thinking that since the service needs to be multithreaded anyway (for other design reasons) that having them watch each other would be a nice plus. now i realize though, that if a thread crashes,then the whole application would crash and kill both threads.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that sounds like a feasible solution. The only problem with double threads is that if the application crashes then both threads will die (if they are background threads)
The solution I found useful to this problem is to have a watchdog process. Whenever the worker process crashes, the watchdog kicks in and creates a new instance and runs it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write your application as a class library used by a Windows Service (templates in visual studio, you will need to add installers). **If you run your application this way, you will have the option at any time to set the behavior if something should fail, ie restart always, retart a couple of times, and after that email someone or run this other application, etc.**

It's built into any windows box you have credentials for and all the hard work is done for you. It's always a no brainer for services I need to always be up and running.

To do this you simply, set the service type to Automatic (this will restart it if your box ever gets rebooted), then there are options for the first three restarts needed that you can set for whatever you need from within the [management window](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) in the services section.

more info:
[windows service documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the most robust solution which covers a wide variety of cases is have a watchdog process which can start and stop a worker process. You would use WCF to send signals (or other information) back and forth between the processes. The idea is to keep the watchdog process simple so that there is little chance that it can fail while performing its limited set of tasks. Then put all of the risky logic in the worker process.

Come up with a protocol for communicating failures or the health of the worker process to the watchdog process. Here are a few ideas. This list is by no means an exhaustive list.

- Watchdog restarts worker process if it does not receive a status report in timely manner.
- Watchdog restarts worker process if it receives a failure status report.
- Watchdog restarts worker process if it detects a memory leak.
- Watchdog starts worker process if it is not running.

Aside from the last item the Windows service control manager cannot handle the other 3 cases. This is one reason why I like the watchdog process idea. Another reason is because your main logic may hang up on a blocking call. Since `Thread.Abort` is not recommend because it corrupts state you really have very few options except to kill the worker process anyway.

Also, try making your main logic as fault tolerant as possible. That way if you do need to forcefully terminate it then it is a lot easier to recover and cleanup the mess it left behind. This may mean using atomic operations like DB transactions or clever file operations.